# Adding Selected Properties to List and return as API Call in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, api, anonymous-types

I am getting a list of object as a return from function call. I want to add only few properties of object to anonymous object and return it. Can you please let me know how to do?

```
var destinationSelectedProperties = new { code = string.Empty, name = string.Empty };
var destinations = pricerepository.GetDestinationsBasedOnMarketAndProgram(salesItemRequest);

if (destinations == null || !destinations.Any())
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);

destinations.ToList().ForEach(u => {
                destinationSelectedProperties = new
                {
                    code = u.Code,
                    name = u.Name
                };
            });
```

The code is as shown above. Here the code returns only the last value in the object as shown below

```
{
    "code": "US-WAS",
    "name": "Washington, D.C."
}
```

If the list has 3 values,I want to return all the values of the list as shown below:

```
[
{
    "code": "US-WAS",
    "name": "Washington, D.C."
},
{
    "code": "US-SSS",
    "name": "London"
},
{
    "code": "US-GBL",
    "name": "Global"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of single variable, we can get the `anonymous` object's list, and return it directly.

```
 // we need to comment it as its a single variable, 
 //var destinationSelectedProperties = new { code = string.Empty, name = string.Empty };

var destinations = pricerepository.GetDestinationsBasedOnMarketAndProgram(salesItemRequest);

if (destinations == null || !destinations.Any())
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);

return destinations.Select(u =>new
                {
                    code = u.Code,
                    name = u.Name
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: @shrinivas,
Mark this as answer if this helped you to solve your issue

Comment: @Deepak Sharma, Thank you so much :) It helped me